# Autocomplete with json response in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am using Autocomplete widget to filter the items from the JSON response. I have binded the reponse with the source, but the filter doesn't happen. Here is the code

```
The JSON Response:

[{"SupplierID":1234,"SupplierName":"Desco"},    
{"SupplierID":1222,"SupplierName":"Festive"}
]

Jquery:
$.ajax({
type: "GET",
url: "http://api-test.example.com/Suppliers",
dataType: "json",
headers:{Authorization:authHeader},
success: function (result) {
        debugger;
        console.log(result);
        console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
         $( "#supplier" ).autocomplete({
          minLength: 0,
          source: JSON.stringify(result),
          focus: function( event, ui ) {
          debugger;
            $( "#supplier" ).val( ui.item.SupplierName );
            return false;
          },
          select: function( event, ui ) {
            $( "#supplier" ).val( ui.item.SupplierName );
            $( "#supplier-id" ).val( ui.item.SupplierID );
            alert(ui.item.SupplierID);

            return false;
          }
          })
          .data( "ui-autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
              return $( "<li>" )
                .append( "<a>" + item.SupplierName  + "</a>" )
                .appendTo( ul );
            };

        };
    }
```

When i search the Supplier filter, the results doesn't get displayed.
Ho to fix this?

Comment: The results dont get displayed, but what happens instead? Is the text box set to a value?

Comment: @AmmarCSE When i types in, the autocomplete doesn't work and when the typed text is removed completely, the filter list comes out and then am able to select the list items. I have set the value in the focus event $( "#supplier" ).val( ui.item.SupplierName )

Comment: Hey @user3554548, have you figured it out, or do you still need help?

Comment: @AmmarCSE, I got the solution, returned the json response and then formatted as label and value in an array. Finally bounded to the source. Thanks